# reassigning self.__class__ automatically at the beginning of each method using a class decorator?

Tags: python

I have recently experimented with reload(). Let us consider the following simple module `mother_and_child_in_same_file.py`:

```
class mother( object ):

    def foobar( self ):

        print "foobar mother"

class child( mother ):

    def foobar( self ):

        self.__class__ = child
        # None of the two following methods is correctly working after a reload,
        # except if we
        # add the previous line concerning __class__; then both methods work
        # correctly.
        mother.foobar( self )
        #super( child, self ).foobar()

        print "foobar child"
```

Used in the script:

```
import mother_and_child_in_same_file

a = mother_and_child_in_same_file.child()

a.foobar()

print "============ RELOAD"
reload( mother_and_child_in_same_file )

a.foobar()
```

It results in the expected output

```
$ python mother_and_child_in_same_file_TEST.py 
foobar mother
foobar child
============ RELOAD
foobar mother
foobar child
```

But only if `self.__class__` is forced as explained in the code.
The problem is thus that existing objects may "loose" their class when using reload(), making it necessary to reassign `self.__class__` at the beginning of every method of these objects, such that no error is obtained when calling the mother (if I understand correctly).
This is rather heavy, and I have tried to do this automatically using a class decorator. Here is the `mother_and_child_in_same_file_decorator.py` module:

```
def my_decorator( cls ):

    def prepend_cls_instance_method_with_class_update( m ):

        def prepended_method( self, *args ):

            self.__class__ = cls
            print "After: self.__class__ = %s" % self.__class__
            m( self, *args )

        return prepended_method

    for method_name in dir( cls ):
        if method_name[:2] == "__":
            continue
        method = getattr( cls, method_name )
        if hasattr( method, '__call__' ):
            prepended_method = prepend_cls_instance_method_with_class_update( method )
            print "setattr( %s, '%s', %s )" % ( cls, method_name, prepended_method )
            setattr( cls
                    , method_name
                    , prepended_method )

    return cls

class mother( object ):

    def foobar( self ):

        print "foobar mother"

@my_decorator
class child( mother ):

    def foobar( self ):

        # None of the two following methods is correctly working.
        #super( child, self ).foobar()
        mother.foobar( self )

        print "foobar child"
```

And the script that uses it:

```
import mother_and_child_in_same_file_decorator as mother_and_child_in_same_file

a = mother_and_child_in_same_file.child()

a.foobar()

print "============ RELOAD"
reload( mother_and_child_in_same_file )

a.foobar()
```

This results in:

```
$ python mother_and_child_in_same_file_decorator_TEST.py 
setattr( <class 'mother_and_child_in_same_file_decorator.child'>, 'foobar', <function prepended_method at 0x7fd467568b18> )
Before: self.__class__ = <class 'mother_and_child_in_same_file_decorator.child'>
foobar mother
foobar child
============ RELOAD
setattr( <class 'mother_and_child_in_same_file_decorator.child'>, 'foobar', <function prepended_method at 0x7fd467568c80> )
Before: self.__class__ = <class 'mother_and_child_in_same_file_decorator.child'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mother_and_child_in_same_file_decorator_TEST.py", line 10, in <module>
    a.foobar()
  File "/home/local/mse6s3/src/python/test/reload_and_super/mother_and_child_in_same_file/mother_and_child_in_same_file_decorator.py", line 9, in prepended_method
    m( self, *args )
  File "/home/local/mse6s3/src/python/test/reload_and_super/mother_and_child_in_same_file/mother_and_child_in_same_file_decorator.py", line 43, in foobar
    mother.foobar( self )
TypeError: unbound method foobar() must be called with mother instance as first argument (got child instance instead)
```

I have tried different variants of this code, without success. What is wrong with my code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `reload` is intended for interactive use; if you're trying to reload the module in production code, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: @ShadowRanger. You're probably right it is better to avoid reloads in production (i.e. "non-debug", i.e. "release") code to avoid errors as the one I have mentioned above (that may occur only in some user test case). This means putting all reloads() in a test similar to a "#ifdef DEBUG" in C, which is rather heavy. This is why I looked for a more systematic method to do that. But I abandon that and put flags instead. This means that the scenario described in my answer to progmatico can be tested only in "release" mode, which is a pity since we should be able to test all scenarios in debug.

Comment: When I said "production" code, I meant "anything besides playing around in the interactive interpreter". `reload` is for live development work, where you're editing a module and playing with it interactively as you go. Barring some hypothetical really weird scenarios involving dynamically generated modules, you shouldn't be using it outside of interactive experiments.

Comment: @ShadowRanger. (I forgot to thank you for your answer). In fact I have really a case where the reload() is useful outside the interactive interpreter. This is the following one.

Comment: (see the reply to my original post below)

Answer (score 0):

Just recreate the objects after the reload. It looks much simpler to me, and it will work:

```
import mother_child

a = mother_child.child()
a.foobar()
print "============ RELOAD"
reload(mother_child)
a = mother_child.child()
a.foobar()
```

Comment: Thanks @progmatico. Indeed it will work, but sometimes it is too much complicated to recreate objects. For instance I may have two identical Python programs running in the same Python interpretor (I cannot change this, this is part of the framework). The first one is run on user action; then the second one. If there are reloads in the Python code, object instances created in the first Python program no more recognize their mother (or similar problems), since the mother class or/and child classes have been reloaded in the interpretor.

Comment: (follow-up of my answer above) I can hardly imagine recreating the objects in the first program; I think a solution may be to have one Python interpretor by Python program. This would imply changes in the framework; but for various reasons it is probably not easy to do.

Comment: The only reasonable solution at this stage is to remove reloads() in release code, as explained above in the discussion with ShadowRanger. But some test cases can only be tested in release code, which should not be the case (also said above).

Comment: @user2827908 :  I also thought that heavy object creation would invalidate this, and I agree with ShadowRanger, but didn't have his strong points at hand ;) But documentation on `importlib.reload` mentions caveats and I've read elsewhere advice against its use (precisely because of caveats).

Comment: I have answered my original post to try to explain the problem in a clearer way --- and taking into account your answers. Do not hesitate to comment it further. Thanks again @progmatico.

Answer (score 0):

@ShadowRanger (I forgot to thank you for your answer). In fact in my case the reloads() are necessary during the development for the following reason. The Python interpreter is embedded in a software written in C++. The "embedded interpreter" allows to access some of the C++ data; in addition to that, it allows to run some Python "apps" (small applications with a GUI) in the context of the C++ software (i.e. able to access and modify some C++ data).

When developing such an "app", of course it is needed to run it again and again after every few modifications. This makes reloads() necessary since the embedded interpreter stays alive between each run. Another possibility would be to restart the embedded Python interpreter before restarting the App, but at this time it is not possible.

A problem appears with reloads() since it is possible to execute two or more identical "apps" mentioned above in the embedded interpreter. If reloads are present in the imported modules, objects created in the first started "apps" do not recognize their mother/child (errors similar to the one of my original post appear). This is why in this framework it is now clear that I should (i) use reload() only during development (debug flag), (ii) run only one "app" at a time during development --- the scenario where multiple "apps" run at the same time should be tested only in release code (no debug flag --- so no reload()).